# Add ImageButton to Custom View

Tags: android, image, button, view

Hi there I have a class that extends the View class. I override the method onDraw do create my custom view and then on my activity I set the content view creating an instance of my custom view.

How can I inside my custom view class add a new ImageButton to a specific region?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: anyone there to help?

Comment: I highly recommend you to go for SlideNerd videos on YouTube. The guy has a perfect grasp on the subject and you can find any aspect a beginner might need among his videos.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzrGAZnMOMQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa